# Can't link new repositories to projects using Bitbucket's API

Tags: python, python-requests, bitbucket-api

I'm building a shell application that allows my teammates to start new projects by running a few commands. It should be able to create a new project and a new repository inside that project.

Although I'm specifying the project key/uuid when creating a new repository, it doesn't work. What I'm expecting is a success message with the details for the new repository. Most of the time, this is what I get:

```
{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "string indices must be integers", "id": "ef4c2b1b49c74c7fbd557679a5dd0e58"}}
```

or the repository goes to the first project created for that team (which is the default behaviour when no project key/uuid is specified, according to Bitbucket's [API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D#post)).

So I'm guessing there's something in between my request & their code receiving it? Because it looks like they're not even getting the request data.

```
# Setup Request Body
rb = {
    "scm": "git",
    "project": {
        "key": "PROJECT_KEY_OR_UUID"
    }
}

# Setup URL
url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/TEAM_NAME/REPOSITORY_NAME"

# Request
r = requests.post(url, data=rb)
```

Comment: Please give an actual [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe better now?

Comment: Well does that code give the error about string indices needing to be integers? Then could you give that traceback? Or an unexpected response? In which case could you give details of that? You've got the *code*, but not the *result*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well the only way to test that is by making an actual request. I've added the response I'm getting though.

Answer (score 0):

In the code from the api docs you'll notice that the Content-Type header is "application/json".

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "scm": "git",
    "project": {
        "key": "MARS"
    }
}' https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/teamsinspace/hablanding
```

In your code you're passing your data in the `data` parameter, which creates an "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" Content-Type header, and urlencodes your post data.

Instead, you should use the `json` parameter.

```
rb = {
    "scm": "git",
    "project": {
        "key": "PROJECT_KEY_OR_UUID"
    }
}

url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/TEAM_NAME/REPOSITORY_NAME"
r = requests.post(url, json=rb)
```